# Javascript array splice equivalant for objects

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```
myObject = {
"member.1": "98bbe8c6-48db-990eeec325"
"member.2": "cc0419d3-6c97-xcd32d3ba6"
"member.3": "dba16933-b972-34fee1fefc"
"member.4": "bb32b6e7-1ac2-a687295acb"
"member.5": "a4fe92cf-2640-8f77d2c44e"
"member.6": "b2e9b23c-3dab-3fba8195b3"
}
```

I want to be able to split it into smaller object like I split array into subarrays with the splice methods.

```
myObject1 = {
"member.1": "98bbe8c6-48db-990eeec325"
"member.2": "cc0419d3-6c97-xcd32d3ba6"
}
myObject2 = {
"member.3": "dba16933-b972-34fee1fefc"
"member.4": "bb32b6e7-1ac2-a687295acb"
}
myObject2 = {
"member.5": "a4fe92cf-2640-8f77d2c44e"
"member.6": "b2e9b23c-3dab-3fba8195b3"
}
```

Is there a method to do that?

Comment: There sure is, but there's no available ready made method to do it, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Why not use an array to begin with for this (besides, your example is invalid syntax)?

Comment: I didn't make a choice of using an object for this, something I have to live with.

Comment: Your issue is not how to slice an object. Your issue is that you're using the wrong data-structure. Like having strings like `"two hundred fifty-six"` and trying to do calculations with them. The very fact that you have enumerated properties shows you that these should not be properties but a (single) list. Maybe like `myObject = { "members": ["98bbe8c6-48db-990eeec325", ... ] }`? Don't know if there is additional meaning in the property names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to just iterate the properties and assign every N properties to new objects:

```
function splitProperties(myObject, propsPerObject) {
    var propCntr = 0;
    var currentObj = {};
    var newObjects = [];
    for (var prop in myObject) {
        if (propCntr >= propsPerObject) {
            newObjects.push(currentObj);
            currentObj = {};
            propCntr = 0;
        }
        currentObj[prop] = myObject[prop];
        ++propCntr;
    }
    newObjects.push(currentObj);
    return newObjects;
}

var smallerObjects = splitProperties(myObject, 2);
```

This creates an array of new objects each with `propsPerObject` properties on them (except the last object might have fewer properties if the number of total properties isn't evenly divisible).

Answer (score 0):

[underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) has a handy `pick(obj, *keys)` function for that, which looks like this when written out:

```
_.pick = function(obj) {
  var copy = {};
  var keys = concat.apply(ArrayProto, slice.call(arguments, 1));
  each(keys, function(key) {
    if (key in obj) copy[key] = obj[key];
  });
  return copy;
};
```

You'd call it with `myObject1 = _.pick(myObject, 'member.1', 'member.2')` and it would return a copy of `myObject` with only the selected properties. If you want to use it without underscore.js, I'd suggest implementing something like this in plain Javascript.

Comment: If you have access to underscore (or don't mind writing the function yourself), you could also use `_.values` and splice the returned array.

Comment: That's true. I suppose `_.pairs` would be more fitting, but I don't think I completely understand the problem OP is trying to solve.

Comment: AFAIK he just wants to split a big object with lots of properties into several smaller objects that only have some of these properties... which would be the perfect use-case for `pick`, in my opinion. ;)

Comment: `pick` certainly works, but if he knows the keys he needs to split before runtime, it would be simpler to just create object literals like: `myObject1 = {"member.1": myObject["member.1"], "member.2": myObject["member.2"]};`

Comment: Yes, but only if he knows the keys at runtime and they're not decided on dynamically. ;) In any case, the whole approach seems to be a bit misguided, hence the downvote(s).